# Failed to find provider info for .fileprovider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have a task to create a file and send it by email through a mail application. I have fileProvider in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    ... >

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.test.example.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
    ...
</application>
```

I also added paths to provider_paths is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external-path"
        path="."/>
    <external-files-path
        name="external-files-path"
        path="."/>
    <files-path
        name="files_path"
        path="."/>
</paths>
```

Then I create a file and give it through the URI. Next, I create an intent to send a letter via email

```
suspend fun collectLogsToFile(): Uri {
    val logcatFile = File(context.filesDir, "logcat.log")

    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { BufferedOutputStream(FileOutputStream(logcatFile.path)).use { stream ->
            stream.write("test".toByteArray())
        }
    }
    if (!logcatFile.exists()) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            logcatFile.createNewFile()
        }
    }

    return FileProvider.getUriForFile(
        context,
        "com.test.example.fileprovider",
        logcatFile
    )
}

private suspend fun createEmailIntent(): Intent {
    val logFileUri = collectLogsToFile()

    return Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO).apply {
        addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        data = Uri.parse("mailto:")
        putExtra(
            Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
            arrayOf(DEVELOPERS_EMAIL)
        )
        putExtra(
            Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
            "text"
        )
        putExtra(
            Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
            "subject"
        )
        putExtra(
            Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
            logFileUri
        )
    }
}
```

but I, when I open the Google mail app or another mail app, I get error:

```
E  Failed to find provider info for com.test.example.fileprovider
E  ComposeActivity: Error adding attachment [CONTEXT                                                                                                 
    geq: FileNotFoundException when openAssetFileDescriptor.
    at fyx.f(PG:28)                                                                                          
    at gmz.I(PG:4)                                                                                       
    at gll.run(PG:59)                                                                                                       
    at gmz.at(PG:31)                                                                                         
    at gmz.as(Unknown Source:6)                                                                                          
    at fyz.a(PG:86)                                                                                          
    at aswv.c(PG:2)                                                                                          
    at aswx.run(PG:9)                                                                                        
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)                                                                                       
    at aqkz.run(PG:3)                                                                                        
    at airh.run(PG:81)                                                                                       
    at aqjm.run(PG:29)                                                                                       
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)                                                                                       
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)                                                                                       
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)                                                                                       
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653)                                                                                         
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                        
    at 
    com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)                                                                                        
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)                                                                                     
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: 
    content://com.test.example.fileprovider/files_path/logcat.log
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1979)                                                                                                   
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1808)                                                                                                    
    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1724)
    at fyx.f(PG:23)
    at gmz.I(PG:4) 
    at gll.run(PG:59) 
    at gmz.at(PG:31) 
    at gmz.as(Unknown Source:6) 
    at fyz.a(PG:86) 
    at aswv.c(PG:2) 
    at aswx.run(PG:9) 
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462) 
    at aqkz.run(PG:3) 
    at airh.run(PG:81) 
    at aqjm.run(PG:29) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

But I always get the fileContentProvider error. Tell me, please, what am I doing wrong? I was looking for a lot of similar questions and did. as I seem to think correctly
What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: You are sending an empty file.

Comment: @blackapps I updated code. I write string to file, but error has not disappeared

Comment: `data = Uri.parse("mailto:")` Please remove.

Comment: If that does not help than put your uri as data.

Comment: @blackapps `data = logFileUri`?

Comment: @blackapps I find solution, i create ACTION_SEND intent instead ACTION_SEND_TO